# Is there a way to send an http post request on your android device/emulator without getting this error?

Tags: android, angular, http, httpclient, ionic4

Been trying to send a post Http request from my android device but for some reason, it doesn't work due to '`ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`'.

Tried to run the very same code on my browser it works just fine.

---

**`Service.ts` function:**

```
    constructor(private  http: HttpClient) { }

  send(data: any) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods' , 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE' );
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers' , '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'true');
    headers.append('responseType', 'application/json');

    return  this.http.post(
      'http://api', '' , {headers}
    );
    }
```

---

**`config.xml`:**

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources\android\splash\drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```

**`network_security_config.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

---

**`AndroidManifest.xml`:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

> Error message  [image]

Already tried to add

```
cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" to network_security_config.xm
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" to AndroidManifest.xml
```

Comment: you might wanna format your code so that it's easier to read. For Eg: I generally prefer each xml attribute in a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using https instead of http but then I added the

> cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"

property in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file instead of using it in **network_security_config**, now it works with both https and http.

in **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
  <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >

.....code.....

</application>
```